# Коллекция ArrayList не считывает текстовые данные из файла

Tags: java, arraylist

У меня проблема с ArrayList - есть класс Библиотека, в нем есть перечень книг, которые находятся в текстовом файле и которые надо загнать в ArrayList. Нужно, чтобы ArrayList считывал данные из файла в формате Название, Год, Автор.

Для занесения в файл я прописал метод, который в принципе записывает текстовую информацию из консоли в текстовый файл. Но все бы было хорошо, если бы мне просто надо было записать в .txt файл текст. Но ничего простого в нашем деле нет, и мне надо задать именно форматированный ввод данных в текстовый файл. Вот тот метод который я использую для записи.

```
if (sc==6){
    System.out.println("Введите новую книгу:");
    String filePath = "Lib.txt";
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(out);
        bufferWriter.newLine();
        bufferWriter.write(console.next());
        bufferWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Вот пример метода который я использую для чтения

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Bks books = new Bks ();
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<Bk> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 new FileInputStream("Lib.txt"), "Cp1251"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] items = line.split(",");
            list.add(new Bk(items[0], items[1], Integer.parseInt(items[2])));
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    books.setArr(list);
```

Посоветуйте, что мне надо сюда добавить, и что поменять?

Comment: А что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Проблем в принципе тут много. Нужно задать форматированный ввод через консоль, что бы программа запрашивала, сначала Название, затем Год, а затем Автора. Потом это все надо записать в текстовый файл, и затем считать это все обратно в консоль. Я так понимаю, что метод записи, должен записывать данные в ячейки ArrayList. Которые находятся в строчке--  list.add(new Bk(items[0], items[1], Integer.parseInt(items[2])));  Но как это сделать я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, попробуйте, пожалуйста, конструкцию с reader.ready():

```
while(reader.ready()){
    String readLine = reader.readLine();
    if(readLine != null){
        // операции со строкой
    }
}
```

Для форматированной записи строчек в файл можно использовать String.format() с параметрами:

```
    String stringValue = "Я строка!";
    int integerValue = 42;
    String s = String.format("%1$s,%2$d", stringValue,integerValue);

    // s == "Я строка!,42"
```

А далее общие рекомендации (если эта программа рассматривается как рабочий проект, а не учебное упражнение):

1. Лучше работать с юникодом (кодировка utf-8 вместо cp1251). Это сделает возможным использование приложения в системах по всему миру.
2. В качестве хранилища данных для такого приложения могут подойти SQLite или MongoDB. По опыту скажу, что MongoDB весьма прост и удобен, когда дело касается хранения небольших текстовых записей, плюс меньше мороки с форматированием данных - просто записываем значения для полей (название, автор и т.д.), а монго сохранит записи как надо. Плюс, удобное представление данных в JSON формате, если понадобится передать что-то по сети (например, мобильной версии приложения).

UPD:
Чтобы программа запросила название, год и автора организуйте диалог с пользователем:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);        
System.out.print("Введите название книги: ");
if(console.hasNextLine()){
    name = console.nextLine();
}
System.out.print("Введите дату: ");
if(console.hasNextLine()){
    date = console.nextLine();
}
System.out.print("Введите Автора: ");
if(console.hasNextLine()){
    author = console.nextLine();
}

// \t - символ табуляции
String line = String.format("%1$s\t%2$s\t%3$s", name,date,author);
System.out.println(line);
```

Далее, полученную строку (вместо табуляции можно использовать любой символ: запятую, как у Вас или точку с запятой ";", как в CSV формате) можно спокойно записывать в файл.

Для вывода данных из файла - запускаете цикл считывания данных из файла, заполняете строками (nextLine) экземпляр ArrayList (можете разбить разделителем каждую строку и пересобрать с нужным форматом: сначала `split([разделитель])`, потом `String.format([шаблон строки],[данные])`), а далее - выводите порциями, например, по 10 наименований.

```
List<String> library = new ArrayList<>();

// для примера, заполняю лист почти одинаковыми строками
for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
    library.add(line + Math.random());
}

for(int counter = 0; counter < library.size(); counter++){
    System.out.println(library.get(counter));
    if(counter % 10 == 0){
        console.nextLine();
    }
}
```